# Merge two files AWK

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have to merge two files and need help with:

File1.csv

```
mac-test-2,10.57.8.2,Compliant
mac-test-6,10.57.8.6,Compliant
mac-test-12,10.57.8.12,Compliant
mac-test-17,10.57.8.17,Noncompliant
```

File2.csv

```
mac-test-17,10.57.8.17,2022-10-21
```

After Merge the content should be
Merge.csv

```
mac-test-2,10.57.8.2,Compliant,NA
mac-test-6,10.57.8.6,Compliant,NA
mac-test-12,10.57.8.12,Compliant,NA
mac-test-17,10.57.8.17,Noncompliant,2022-10-21
```

so logic is if the File1.txt doesnt have a matching record in File2.txt then "NA" should be inserted and if it is a match then date should be inserted in the fourth column.

I have written below

```
awk -F "," '
ARGV[1] == FILENAME{a[$1];next}
{
 if ($1 in a) {  
    print $0 ","
 } else {
  print $0 ",NA"
 }
}
' File2.csv File1.csv
```

But this is printing

```
mac-test-2,10.57.8.2,Compliant,NA
mac-test-6,10.57.8.6,Compliant,NA
mac-test-12,10.57.8.12,Compliant,NA
mac-test-17,10.57.8.17,Noncompliant,
```

I am not sure how I can print the date if it matches.

Comment: Your attempt (and the accepted question) assume, that File2.csv contains at most one line. Can your really assume this?

Comment: @user1934428, there is already a solution which takes care in case it's an empty file was added by me in answer.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Empty file, yes. That's why I wrote **at most one line**. But how about a file with i.e. 2 lines?

Comment: @user1934428, an array is being created to make comparison from file1.csv so IMHO it doesn't matter how many lines are there.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : Right! Sorry, I missed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested with your shown samples only.

```bash
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]=$NF
  next
}
{
  print $0,($1 in arr?arr[$1]:"NA")
}
' file2.csv file1.csv
```

**To handle empty file2.csv** please try following `awk` program.

```bash
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
ARGV[1] == FILENAME{
  arr[$1]=$NF
  next
}
{
  if ($1 in arr) {
    print $0,arr[$1]
  }
  else{
    print $0,"N/A"
 }
}' file2.csv file1.csv
```

Comment: This works when file2 has data and if file2 is empty it doesnt attach NA to all the lines in File1. Please help

Comment: @snigdhasingh, looks like it was not mentioned in your question . Let me add that in a min here.

Comment: sorry, I figured out. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @snigdhasingh, Good to hear that and happy to help you. I have added alternative solution also which handles the empty file2.csv scenario also. Cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Good to see use of `ARGV[1]` in first condition to handle empty files